# Are there any diacritics derived from superscripted "i" (and other letters)?

Tags: orthography, writing-systems, diacritics, umlaut

I know that umlaut (e.g. ä) derives from superscripted "e", ring (e.g. å) derives from superscripted "a", and tilde (e.g. ñ) derives from superscripted "n".

Is there a diactritic that derives from superscripted "i"?

Comment: Not superscripted, but the Greek _iota subscriptum_ is – as the name pretty heavily implies – from a subscripted i(ota).

Comment: The West Syriac alphabet (abjad) has a [system of vowel diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_alphabet#Vowels_2) consisting of the superscripted and subscripted Greek letters Α, α, ε, H, OΥ, ω, with capital eta (H) representing [i].

Comment: I suspect that the use of acute accent to mark palatal consonants in Polish (e.g. ś) derives from a superscript *i* over the consonant, but you would have to inspect photos of ancient manuscripts to be certain.